# "Required field 'resource.name' not specified"

Tags: rest

I am trying to use the REST message to create an instance on Google Compute Engine.

I use the exact same rest message that I get from the REST link on the standard console page.

---

```
POST <post url>
{
  "name": "instance-1",
  "zone": "projects/service-now-16699/zones/us-east1-c",
  "machineType": "projects/service-now-16699/zones/us-east1-c/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
  "metadata": {
    "items": []
  },
  "tags": {
    "items": [
      "http-server",
      "https-server"
    ]
  },
  "disks": [
    {
      "type": "PERSISTENT",
      "boot": true,
      "mode": "READ_WRITE",
      "autoDelete": true,
      "deviceName": "instance-1",
      "initializeParams": {
        "sourceImage": "<image-url>",
        "diskType": "projects/service-now-16699/zones/us-east1-c/diskTypes/pd-ssd",
        "diskSizeGb": "10"
      }
    }
  ],
  "canIpForward": false,
  "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "network": "projects/service-now-16699/global/networks/default",
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "name": "External NAT",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "description": "",
  "scheduling": {
    "preemptible": false,
    "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
    "automaticRestart": true
  },
  "serviceAccounts": [
    {
      "email": "service-now-16699@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

However, when I execute I am getting the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required field 'resource.name' not specified"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required field 'resource.name' not specified"
 }
}
```

I can't find any reference to 'resource.name'.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Saurabh